# Get label for AutoForm option value in Meteor Simple Schema

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

In Meteor template `{{parameter}}` returns value of option for this schema:

```
new SimpleSchema({
  parameter: {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: ['value_1', 'value_2'],
    autoform: {
      options: [
        {label: "label_1", value: 'value_1'},
        {label: "label_2", value: 'value_2'}
      ]
    }
  },
});
```

How can I get `label` instead of `value` in my template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
  label: function (value) {
    return _.findWhere(YourSchema.schema('parameter').autoform.options, { value: value }).label;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I need.